# PHP form submit not returning all values from the form

Tags: php, forms, request, form-submit

I have a form with n numbers of data. When I click submit on request (`$_REQUEST`), I could receive only 1st 50 data.

The form field inputs are in an array. What could be the issue?

Sample code:

```
<div class="DTE_Field_Type_text DTE_Field_Name_Branch_name Phone">
   <label data-dte-e="label" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
      Branch Name:
      <div data-dte-e="msg-label" class="DTE_Label_Info"></div>
   </label>
   <div data-dte-e="input" class="col-sm-4">
      <input value="" name="branch_name_48[]" placeholder="Branch Name" id="DTE_Field_branch_name_48" class="form-control-occupancy" required="" type="text">
      <div style="display: none;" data-dte-e="msg-error" class="help-block"></div>
      <div data-dte-e="msg-message" class="help-block"></div>
      <div data-dte-e="msg-info" class="help-block"></div>
   </div>
   <label data-dte-e="label" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
      Branch Address:
      <div data-dte-e="msg-label" class="DTE_Label_Info"></div>
   </label>
   <div data-dte-e="input" class="col-sm-4">
      <textarea name="branch_addr_48[]" placeholder="Branch Address" id="DTE_Field_hq_addr_48" class="form-control-occupancy"></textarea>
      <div style="display: none;" data-dte-e="msg-error" class="help-block"></div>
      <div data-dte-e="msg-message" class="help-block"></div>
      <div data-dte-e="msg-info" class="help-block"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="savenext" name="save" value="Save" type="submit">
```

The form has more fields, i.e `branch_addr_100` and so on. From this form, I could receive only `branch_addr_49`. How could I retrieve all 100 records?

I have shown the data from db and shown in the form where the div's on load are collapsed and given display:none to avoid too much data on the page load.when needed the div's can be expanded.Will that be a problem

Comment: If you have a very large number of fields on a form check the value of `max_input_vars` in your `php.ini` The default is `max_input_vars = 2500` but if you have more than that you will need to increase it and then restart Apache

Comment: @RiggsFolly It defaults to 1000.

Comment: You may also need to increase `max_input_time = 60` and `memory_limit = 128M`

Comment: @Barmar Not in my `php.ini` but then I am a Windows WAMPServer user so I probably dont count. :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Hi, The max_input_vars is 1000 that could be more at present.i have shown the datas from db and shown in the form where the divs on load are collapsed and given display:none to avoid too much data on the page load.when needed the divs can be expanded.Will that be a problem?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The default is what's used when there's nothing in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I realised that after my silly comment. I seem to remember we up that limit as part of the build of WAMPServer and its PHP ADDON installs.

Comment: I think the `display:none` inputs will get sent to the script anyway

Comment: @Barmer Hi, Within a form i have a phone number field i.e 4 text boxes with a option to add more phone fields. When i hide the phone fields i could able to retrieve all the 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is, limit of `max_input_vars` exceeds in your case.

There a limit to the maximum number of form elements in (one nesting level) like it is controlled by the `php.ini` directive `max_input_vars`. So you have to increase that limit to get all values.